# How to redirect logging in akka?

Tags: scala, logging, akka

I am implementing a distributed database with scala 2.9 and akka 2.0. My current problem is I want to redirect the standard logging to a file instead of stdout. I don't realy want to use SLF4J or SLF4S. Is there a simple way to redirect the logging output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The akka documentation for logging says, that you can register handlers in the config like this:

```
akka {
  # Event handlers to register at boot time (Logging$DefaultLogger logs to STDOUT)
  event-handlers = ["akka.event.Logging$DefaultLogger"]
  # Options: ERROR, WARNING, INFO, DEBUG
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
}
```

There is also an SLF4J handler

```
akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler
```

Using this you can add any SLF4J compliant library like logback to write your logs to wherever you want.

edit:

To use logback to log to a file you have to add logback as a dependency, add the Slf4jEventHandler to your config:

```
akka {
  # Event handlers to register at boot time (Logging$DefaultLogger logs to STDOUT)
  event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]
  # Options: ERROR, WARNING, INFO, DEBUG
  loglevel = "DEBUG"
}
```

and add a logback config to your project that lokks something like this (taken from logback docs):

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>testFile.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Due to the async logging in akka you cannot use the %thread variable in your log pattern, instead use the `sourceThread` variable from the MDC. You can read about that at the bottom of this page: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/logging.html

You don't have to explicitly use slf4j or logback in your code, just use the normal akka logging, the handler will take care of everything else.

Comment: Yes I found that to. But is there another way than use SLF4J to redirect the logging output?

Comment: As far as i can tell there is no FileLogger in akka itself, but you could implement one yourself. But what is wrong with SLF4J?

Comment: Nothing at all. I just hoped there is another way like setting a variable in the config file.

Comment: Basically it is that + adding the dependency and the config for the logging library.

Comment: Excuse me but I didn't understand your last comment. Can you give me an example?

Comment: You can create your own handler, read the docs: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/scala/logging.html

Comment: Just an FYI: In order to get an slf4j compatible logger like Logback to work, you need to add some dependencies: `"com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-slf4j" % "2.0.3"` (from an additional resolver `resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"`) and `"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.0.7"`